# rails ajax redirect is using wrong controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, routes

I`m trying to do ajax redirect to my 'on_clan_change' custom controller action..

I`m calling ajax by this function:

```
$(document).on 'change', '#character_clan_id', ->
  $.ajax
    url: 'on_clan_change'
    type: 'GET'
    dataType: 'script'
    data: {
      clan_id: $("#character_clan_id option:selected").val() }
```

And it generates link like this:

```
Started GET "/users/1/characters/on_clan_change?clan_id=101&_=1461614074287"
```

I have set routes like this:

```
  resources :users, only: [:show, :index] do
    resources :characters
    get 'characters/on_clan_change', to: 'characters#on_clan_change'
  end
```

From my rake routes:

```
 user_on_clan_change GET    /users/:user_id/characters/on_clan_change(.:format)         characters#on_clan_change
```

In my characters controller I have a defined function `on_clan_change`

But when redirect is done it is using `characters#show` action. It looks like it gives me show action as default. But since route seems to be correct I have no idea why it is using wrong action.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to set this link was:

```
  resources :users, only: [:show, :index] do
    resources :characters do
      collection do
        get 'on_clan_change'
      end
    end
  end
```